# Hit the question ban even though my question was well-recieved

Tags: discussion, questions

I just asked [a question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-letting-users-define-functions-with-the-same-name). It appears to be quite well-recieved by the community (score of 1), however when I accidentally clicked the ask question button I hit the question ban.

Does anyone know what is happening here? Why have I hit the question ban for a good question?

Comment: I don't know exactly how the question limiting works, but you also have [a -5 question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/301/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-implementing-indexed-for-loops) and [one with seven total downvotes](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/what-does-the-name-of-a-programming-language-say-about-the-language) so there may well be a volume limit in place for the moment that allows *one* question in a period of time — it isn't necessarily because of the most recent post.

Comment: If it is that, I believe the effects wear off over time, and that a well-received question makes them wear off faster, so it's just about waiting for a bit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Homer said in comments, you didn’t’t hit the question ban for that question, but rather from previous poor questions. [As the meta faq post states:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

That is what I think happened here, But, your one question wasn’t well received enough to lift you out of the ban.